# VOD Media Server for desktop and mobile

Tags: android, ios, streaming, desktop, ondemand

In my website there are flv videos playing with jwplayer. Now I have to port the site on mobile and iOS doesn't play flash video..

Main Features I have to follow:

- Play on Desktop, Andorid and iOS.
- Stream only parts of (big) videos.
- Seek functionality.
- Can not have 2 same video in different formats.

I'm thinking about [Wowza Media Server](http://www.wowza.com/). Has anyone tried that?
Other solutions may be [red5](http://www.red5.org/) or [Mistserver](http://www.mistserver.org/): Any Opinions and suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Wowza is my favourite streaming server, however it does not support streaming FLV via HLS (best streaming protocol for iOS). So I guess you'll need some ffmpeg transcoding script setup to transcode all your flv files to mp4 files. Wowza will handle the rest of requested features like multi-protocol multi-device streaming, seeking, playing parts of video, and much more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying wowza and it seems great. As you said FLV via HLS is not supported and now I'm using MP4 video sample of Wowza Media Server. I need to seek in video: with HLS + iOS there are no probles, but with Android I'm not able to seek with HLS or RTSP streaming. Do you stream for iOS and Android? If yes, what are you using for streaming in Android? Are you able to seek in a video? Thank you very much.